# HTML and Java Servlet: the values of selected checkboxes in servlet have the same order of their checkboxes in HTML?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have a page with the following checkboxes

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Milk"> Milk<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Butter"> Butter<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="Cheese"> Cheese<br>
```

If any two or all of them are checked, I am able to get the checked values in a servlet as follows:

```
String[] results = request.getParameterValues("option");
```

My question is: the order of the selected values in the results array is guaranteed to match the order of checkboxes in HTML?

For example: If Mike and Cheese are selected in HTML, then the values in results MUST be: results[0= Milk and results[1]=Cheese.

Is there any specification about this?

Comment: I don't think so. You can inject some sortable data into 'value' and do sorting on servlet. For example: Milk_0, Butter_1 and Cheese_2

Comment: I did some tests. It appears the order in HTML matches the order in the servlet. However, I am not sure whether there is specs for this. Otherwise, the results may vary with the servlet container.

Comment: You could search HTML specification if this topic is there. Otherwise it is not guaranteed and the order is implementation dependant. And even if the ordering was specified, IE 6 will have different behaviour :-)